# Azure Search Select within nested collections

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

Currently, we are using Azure Cosmos Db but thought of using Azure Search because of its ability to handle the fuzzy search, misspellings, synonym maps etc. But since Azure Search will become our primary search, we will end up indexing nested collections too.

Our current schema is as follows:

```
{
  "id": "0010010011001",
  "partitionKey": "001001001",
  ...
  ...
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "abc",
      “category”: “A”,
      “subItems”: [
         {
              "id": 1,
              "level": "1",
              “rank”: “1”,
              “description”: “abc”
         },
         {
              "id": 2,
              "level": "1",
              “rank”: “2”,
              “description”: “def”
         },
         {
              "id": 3,
              "level": "2",
              “rank”: “3”,
              “description”: “xyz”
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "def",
      “category”: “A” ,
      “subItems”: [
         ….
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "xyz",
      “category”: “B” ,
      “subItems”: [
         ….
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Our requirement is that we will have three filters, Name (fuzzy search), Category and Rank. And we have to select only those items from documents where Name / Category matches and also we have to also select only those subItems within Items where Rank matches. While querying Cosmos, I was making a join query to items and to subItems but not sure how to query and select elements here.

Answer (score 0):

I am an engineer on Azure Cognitive Search. I'm going to restate your requirements and some of my assumptions below (as the question is a bit unclear) just to confirm that I've interpreted them correctly:

**Assumptions:**

- You're indexing your data such that you dedicate an entire index to "items, and "subItems" is modeled as a complex collection field. We support a maximum depth of 10 for complex fields:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#index-limits

**Requirements:**

- Fuzzy search on the "Name" field (must be searchable)
- Filter search results that match on the "Category" field (must be filterable)
- Filter search results that match on the "Rank" field within the "subItems" field (rank must be filterable)
- Select subItems (discarding top-level id, name, category, etc - you can easily keep them by selecting more fields you're interested in)

**Solution**:

Use this query:

```
searchFields=name&search=<string>~&$filter=category eq '<string2>' AND subItems/all(subItem: subItem/rank eq '<string3>')&select=items/subItems
```

**Reference Docs**

If you'd like to learn more about modeling complex data types within Azure Cognitive Search, I've included a link to some excellent docs below: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types

Comment: Let me just clear one more misinformation here. This entirely is one document which has some fields and Items which is Collection of Compex type. Items itself has some fields and then SubItems which is again a Collection of Complex Type.

Your query is almost correct. The only thing is, you mentioned category in $filters at root level but in my case, category comes under Items so we will need to filter category just like subItems->rank.

The problem in my case is that we need to select Items and subItems only which match filters. I think $select=items/subItems will select all subItems.

Comment: Sounds like we can tweak the filter statement to also filter on items/Category following the same pattern as items/rank. Could you expand on your second concern with "select[ing] Items and subItems only which match filters"? With the query above, the filter will produce a list of index fields that fits the criteria, and the select will select only the subItems value from the filtered list, which sounds like the desired output. Could you provide a short example of the desired output given the index schema shape provided in the original question?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this one. We have a good example in the link you shared https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types
Can you help me with how to write a query for that or how to get the desired result?

Input: City, State, BaseRate say $100
Select: HotelId, Name, Description, Tags, Address, Room Description, Room BaseRate.
Filter: Only rooms where BaseRate is less than or equal to Input rate and Address City and State matches input values.
In this example, it should only select the first room from Rooms.